# Webform 7x-4.10: adding a field type to webforms

Tags: webforms

I'm trying to add an existing field type into the list of available fields Webform can access.

I have a field type of "field_attachment". In my other content types, this allows me to upload a file and all user types can download it.

For one of my webforms, I would like the user (any type) to be able to download a file. They do not need to have answered any questions, so I don't need a protected download lock on it. In fact, that would be counterproductive for what I need.

I can't figure out how to add this field type in admin/config/content/webform. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `field_attachment` is a drupal `Field` type. Webform is it's own system seperate from drupal. I believe there is an `upload field` for webform forms that is similar to the attachment drupal core field you are describing.

Comment: Tenken, you're right: there is an upload field in webform, but that's only for users to upload a doc, not to download one. Thanks for your help, though.